# Reset nload's total counter

Tags: networking

I often setup a hotspot for my laptop via my smartphone. Although I can see on my phone in gigabytes with 1 decimal how much my data usage I've used I would really like to just type nload and have it start counting from zero and show how much "data" I've used since I launched nload. I've looked into vnstat and other programs, but I really like the simplicity and easability of nload had it only counted from zero in the Ttl row.

As of now the total count persists across different nload sessions.

Comment: vnStat can meet those requirements even without the daemon started in the background. Run `vnstat --live 1 -i <interface>` and you'll get the current traffic rates + the incremental totals starting from zero at the startup of the command. When done, break the command with ctrl-c and you'll get a more detailed summary.

Comment: Thanks. I missed `--live mode 1` "...during execution" is while the command runs.